Resources folder path location in iOS .NET MAUI
I am building an archery app to keep score. I have a folder called ScoreData
reData in which I am writing to a file and storing in. When scoring is finished, I want to write the data to a simple .txt file in said folder. For my windows debugging, it is searching the solution using GetEntryAssembly and going up a folder each time until it finds the ScoreData folder. This solution gives me no errors when debugging using "Windows Machine" but when I hook up my iPhone to debug, it throws errors on the GetDirectories() method.
Here is the current code I have that does work with Windows, but throws errors when debugging on an iOS device.
`var anotherDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
//var location = assembly.Location;  
//var dirst = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();  
//var dires = Directory.GetDirectories(dirst.ToString());  
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(anotherDir ?? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
var path = string.Empty;
while (directory != null && !directory.GetFiles("\*.sln").Any())
{
     directory = directory.Parent;
     var folders = directory.GetDirectories();
     if (folders.Length == 9)
     {
          var folder = folders\[6\];
          path = folder.FullName;
     }
}
return path;
`

And here is a screenshot of where I am wanting to get the filepath for when debugging in iOS.
enter image description here

What error did it throw when using GetDirectories() and where do you put the folder? Here is an official doc for File system access in Xamarin.iOS, which  may help you understand.

Looks like your file exists relatively in the solution. Add the .txt as a MauiAsset and set the following in your csproj

<MauiAsset Include="MyFolder\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />


and then you can read the file using
   public async Task<string> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
   {
      using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath);
      using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
      return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }

